# Integrating 2 Python Scripts - Flask & I2C on Pi4

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, i2c, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to write a script which will display which GPIO pins are connected to a common ground on a Pi. This should display on a web page using flask, which works perfectly. It should also display on an i2c display - which doesn't work.

I'm using the below script which is working with flask, however doesn't show on the display.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import smbus
import time
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set up GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
total_pins = 26 
connected_pins = []

# Set up I2C
i2c = smbus.SMBus(1)   
DISPLAY_ADDRESS = 0x27  
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 16  

# Function to read GPIO pin status
def read_gpio(pin):
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    return GPIO.input(pin)

# Function to display connected pins on the I2C display
def display_pins(connected_pins):

    pass

# Web route to display connected pins
@app.route('/')
def index():
    global connected_pins
    connected_pins = []
    
    for pin in range(total_pins):
        if not read_gpio(pin):
            connected_pins.append(pin)

    display_pins(connected_pins)

    return render_template('index.html', connected_pins=connected_pins)

# Route for updating pin status via AJAX
@app.route('/update_pins')
def update_pins():
    global connected_pins
    connected_pins = []
    
    for pin in range(total_pins):
        if not read_gpio(pin):
            connected_pins.append(pin)

    display_pins(connected_pins)

    return json.dumps({'connected_pins': connected_pins})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

The display does work, as I've used the following script with it and it functions as expected. The settings are the same, and no wiring etc has changed so I'm unsure why it doesn't work in the above script. It's just showing a blank display. Above, I expected connected_pins to show on the display.

```
from RPLCD.i2c import CharLCD
import time

lcd = CharLCD(i2c_expander='PCF8574', address=0x27, port=1, cols=16, rows=2, dotsize=8)
lcd.clear()

lcd.write_string('Testing')
```

Any ideas would be amazing!

Comment: Use in-kernel drivers if it runs on Linux.